# How to update media file timestamp from its metadata

Tags: linux, windows, metadata, reset

When I copied files through different hard disks, the date has been overwritten.  I would like to reset the timestamp of media files especially images from the meta data property like 'Date taken' in windows or the 'create' and 'update' times in linux ?

Does it need a script or is there a command?  Either windows or linux is fine?  Is there a simple way in python?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean the file system time stamps, you can use exiftool.

Your basic command for most images would be

```
exiftool "-FileCreateDate<DateTimeOriginal" "-FileModifyDate<DateTimeOriginal" /path/to/files/
```

For MP4/Mov files, it's a bit more complicated as the embedded time stamps are in UTC and not local time.  You would most likely use this command

```
exiftool -api QuickTimeUTC "-FileCreateDate<CreateDate" "-FileModifyDate<CreateDate" /path/to/files/
```

These commands creates backup files.  Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add [`-r`](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks - this looks like the solution.  Though not sure how to get more information.  How do I get a list of all the tags and also what the options mean.  In your first eg, what is done if create time<original time ? I tried list but it gave me a lot of text that couldnt make sense.  Its much simpler to run the identify command.

Comment: The [documentation](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html) is extensive and further complicated by the fact that exiftool can read over 25,000 different tags, so part of knowing what to do is knowing what tags you want to deal with.  The command in [exiftool FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3) should be what you use, as that will list duplicates, the groups they belong to, and the actual tag names.  The [exiftool forums](https://exiftool.org/forum/) is the best place to get help, as the author is quite active there.

Comment: Forgot to add the [link to the all the tag names](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/), sorted by group.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  But still not sure how to read your command as it still doesnt work.  Should I read it as if FileCreateTime<DateTimeOriginal, it will update FileCreateTIme and then do same for FileUpdateTime?.  Found the tags "Date Taken" from https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=11795.0

Comment: Looks like your command is only updating the metadata i.e Date Taken etc.  I am looking for the reverse i.e use Date Taken and update FileCreateDate.

Comment: The commands I listed copy the timestamp from the embedded EXIF (in the case of jpgs/tiff files) or Quicktime (in the case of MP4/Mov files) into the file system time stamps.  The direction of the arrow shows the direction of copy.  Make sure that you put quotes around arguments that contain greater/less than symbols.  The full list of what tags Windows reads to fill it's properties can be found in [this post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=6591.msg32875#msg32875).

Comment: Yes, I see its updating the system tags - it updates the Date Taken to the Create tags.  However, the system time stays unchanged. Also it looks like this works differently for diff formats .. so I cant run it across my entire folder